# How to read JSON field in Kusto query when fields are dynamic

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am working with the JSON data (below) resulting from following query.

```
SignInLogs
| project AddtionalDetails
```

Results

```
[{"value":"test.com","key":"TenantId"},{"value":"PC100921","key":"PolicyId"},{"value":"f4525425-60ff-42a7-acf4-f88c4266431f","key":"ApplicationId"},{"value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36","key":"Client"},{"value":"SMS","key":"VerificationMethod"},{"value":"+1232123211","key":"PhoneNumber"},{"value":"e000::5890, 128.1.1.1","key":"ClientIpAddress"},{"value":"https://test.com","key":"DomainName"}]
```

I would like to access access a particular filed, e.g. PolicyId, using query `SignInLogs |  Policy=extractjson("$.[1].value", tostring(AdditionalDetails)) | project Policy` . However, since ordering of fields and their presence is not guaranteed so cant always using `[1]` as an index.

Is there better way to access JSON fields where ordering and availability is not promised? like in other languages you can check empty reference and access by key name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let T =datatable(AdditionalDetails:dynamic )[dynamic([{"value":"test.com","key":"TenantId"},{"value":"PC100921","key":"PolicyId"},{"value":"f4525425-60ff-42a7-acf4-f88c4266431f","key":"ApplicationId"},{"value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36","key":"Client"},{"value":"SMS","key":"VerificationMethod"},{"value":"+1232123211","key":"PhoneNumber"},{"value":"e000::5890, 128.1.1.1","key":"ClientIpAddress"},{"value":"https://test.com","key":"DomainName"}])];
T
| mv-apply AdditionalDetails on ( 
    extend IP = iif(AdditionalDetails.key=="ClientIpAddress", tostring(AdditionalDetails.value), ""), 
           PolicyId = iif(AdditionalDetails.key=="PolicyId", tostring(AdditionalDetails.value), "")
   | where isnotempty(IP) or isnotempty( PolicyId) 
   | summarize take_any(IP), take_any(PolicyId)
)
```

| IP | PolicyId |
| --- | --- |
| e000::5890, 128.1.1.1 | PC100921 |

Comment: Thanks, Avnera. When I tried getting more than one value out of JSON it is returning empty for second attribute. Query below return correct value for IP Address but empty for PolicyId (both are present json). SignInLogs | mv-apply AdditionalDetails on 
(
  extend IP = iif(AdditionalDetails.key=="ClientIpAddress", tostring(AdditionalDetails.value), "") | where isnotempty(IP)
)
| mv-apply AdditionalDetails on 
(
  extend PolicyId = iif(AdditionalDetails.key=="PolicyId", tostring(AdditionalDetails.value), "") | where isnotempty(PolicyId)
)
| project
 IP,
 PolicyId,
   AdditionalDetails

Comment: I update the example for your scenario Razi - let me know if this is what you were looking for